# how to trigger new function when a select box gets changed via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxes called 'primaryTag' and 'primaryCategory'

primaryCategory depends on primaryTag

There are also 2 multi-select options called 'tags' and 'categories'.

When a 'primaryTag' changes, the 'tags' should get deselected.

When a 'primaryCategory' changes, the 'categories' multi-select options should get deselected. **Even if the 'primaryCategory' gets changed after the change event on primaryTags, the 'categories' multi-select should be reset.**

I have the following code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#primaryTag").change(function () {
        tagId = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_primaryTag option:selected").val();
        $("#primaryCategory").val("option:first");
        $("#tags *").attr("selected", false);
    });

    $("#primaryCategory").change(function () {
        $("#categories *").attr("selected", false);
    });

});
```

`primaryTag` and `primaryCategory` are select boxes. 
`tags` and `categories` are multi-select boxes.

When I change a primaryTag, the primaryCategory select box gets populated with the default value of the first option as desired. However, I also want the categories multi-select box to be reset (all options deselected). And this is not happening. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the HTML

Comment: can you post your html also, preferably in a jsfiddle

Comment: $('document').ready) should be $(document) not a string it the document object. Also $(function() {}); for short version. $('#categories_select').children().removeAttr('disabled');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('document')` has to be `$(document)`. After that remember the default primary category. On *primary tag* change set the default primary category and reset the tag options. On *primary category* change reset the category options.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iDefault = $("#primaryCategory").val();

    $("#primaryTag").change(function () {
        $("#primaryCategory").val(iDefault);
        $("#tags option").attr("selected", false);
    });

    $("#primaryCategory").change(function () {
        $("#categories option").attr("selected", false);
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cXqxZ/).

=== UPDATE ===

If you want to set the first option of the *primary categories* replace with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#primaryTag").change(function () {
        $("#primaryCategory option:first").attr("selected", true);
        $("#tags option").attr("selected", false);
    });

    $("#primaryCategory").change(function () {
        $("#categories option").attr("selected", false);
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cXqxZ/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

If you want that the categories will be resetted after the *primary category* was resetted, replace the first version with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iDefault = $("#primaryCategory").val();

    $("#primaryTag").change(function () {
        $("#primaryCategory").val(iDefault);
        $("#primaryCategory").change();
        $("#tags option").attr("selected", false);
    });

    $("#primaryCategory").change(function () {
        $("#categories option").attr("selected", false);
    });
});
```

Also see this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/r9d2f/1/).

Comment: I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks, 
I have learned a couple of things. 

However, the real problem was this:-
When I change the primaryTag, the primaryCategory gets update. But the corresponding change event (to deselect categories) is never triggered. 

Here is the modified code: xjsfiddle.net/r9d2f/ 
Hopefully this would clarify the question. 
Many thanks for the effort.

Comment: The code of your jsfiddle is the same as mine (first version). And I can't see a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and guidance. It works and more importantly, I have learned a few things. Now I was able to trace an example in the doc that said - To trigger the event manually, apply .change() without arguments:

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onclick function.

```
<element onclick="newfunction()"></element>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to clear a multi-select box using jQuery:

```
$("#my_select_box").val(null);
```

or

```
$("#my_select_box option").attr("selected",false);
```

The first changes the value of the select element to nothing.  The second removes the selected attribute of all of the options in the select element.

I am guessing the effect of your code is:

```
$("#my_select_box").attr("selected",false);
```

which doesn't work because `#my_select_box` is the actual select element.  Removing the `selected` attribute of the select element itself has no effect because that attribute has meaning only for the options inside it.

You really must try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or the developer tools built into chrome.  They can help immensely in debugging javascript and jQuery code.